# getchar() executes before printf()

Tags: c

In my simple program, when it executes the `getchar` method execute before `printf` method.
Why this happen and how to solve this??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SUCCESS 0

void exit_Pro()
{
    printf("Press any Key to exit: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    getchar();
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    atexit(exit_Pro);

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Platform: Window 7
Compiler(IDE): Eclipse CDT

Comment: Never call `fflush(stdin)` - it's UB - see [man fflush](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/fflush/).

Comment: What makes you think getchar is executing before printf?  printf is executing first, but you see no output because it's buffered.  Perhaps you meant `fflush( stdout )`

Comment: Your code compiles and runs fine on my system.  Not sure why you think there's a problem.  Perhaps stdout buffering is delaying when you see the output on your system?

Comment: I tried your suggestion @WilliamPursell, and didn't work. I see the output after I am getting the input.

Comment: @ron.rothman Yes there is delaying when I see the output

Comment: There's no need to define `SUCCESS`.  `EXIT_SUCCESS` is defined in stdlib.h

Comment: Please include your platform and compiler in the question; might be helpful here (since it works fine on my system--CentOS 5.3 gcc 4.1.2).

Comment: Does the problem still happen when you put the body of exit_Pro directly in main(), instead of calling it indirectly at exit?  Show us the simplest example that still exhibits the problem.

Comment: @ron.rothman The code is edited you can see it :)

Comment: Code looks the same to me.  What I want to know is: Do you see the same problem when you (1) remove the `fflush(stdin)`, (2) remove the `atexit`, and (3) copy the body of `exit_Pro` directly into `main` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I agree with nonsensical: `fflush(stdin)` is a bad thing to do.  Here's [further explanation](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1052863818&id=1043284351).  (And if *9* experienced programmers all told me that I was doing something wrong, I'd believe them.)

Now, to try and help you debug your code, can you tell us whether this simplified code exhibits the same problem on your system?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("Press any Key to exit: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: `stdin` is buffered by design.  Maybe you can read (`fgets`) and simply ignore any chars you don't want?  Here's some [further discussion](http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1044873249&id=1043284392) and a method (though I recommend it only with reservations).  Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Flush "stdin"? printf operates on "stdout". Did you mean to flush that? 
Flushing "stdin" makes no sense.

Comment: True--good point; but not an answer to OP's question.  (And was already pointed out in PaulR's comment above.)

Comment: No I think this *is* an answer.  The OP thinks that `getchar` is being executed first because there is no output, then it waits on a key, then the program exits and `stdout` is flushed.  It looks like `printf` is happening after because there was no newline in the printf and `stdout` was not explicitly flushed.

Comment: Except... in his comment above (response to WilliamPursell 19 mins ago) he says quite clearly that he tried that and didn't work.  Right?

Comment: I question if he actually tried flushing stdout and it didn't work.  I suspect language issues.  In any case, flushing stdin is clearly an error.

Comment: I am flushing `stdin` because I need it in future. This is sample of a program, but after this works I will add some code that read data from console. So, I wrote `fflush(stdin)` .
So, The error doesn't happen because of this line :( You are wrong @nonsensical.
And I tried the code without it and the same algorithm happen that I read from console before output the string.

Comment: Ok, I've made some assumptions about what you were trying to do that seem incorrect based on what you just said. You can flush "stdin" but adding fflush(stdout) before getchar() would force it to be printed at that point, which is what I think you were after?

Answer (score 0):

What if you use `stderr` (which is unbuffered)? It works for me.

```
void exit_Pro()
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Press any Key to exit: ");
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Sheesh. You're right. Thanks. I can't reproduce the original problem (Linux 3.4.6 x86_64, glibc 2.15, gcc 4.7.1).